# Problems rendering BeamerTex Postscript specials in WinEdt 6.0

Tags: beamer, miktex, winedt, yap

I have a beamer `.tex` file which I know works perfectly on TexShop.  However, when I `texify` the same document on WinEdt 6.0, the document does not display properly.  No images appear, and anytime I try to scroll down the document, I get a message saying:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Some PostScript specials could not be rendered.
Data:
Error: /undefined in H.S
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1914   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1897   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:17/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

What can I do to prevent this error and display everything properly?

***Update***

This is how I setup my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!60!blue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=orange!85!blue}

\def\colorize<#1>{%
 \temporal<#1>{\color{black!20}}{\color{black}}{\color{black!20}}}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{My Groundbreaking Presentation}
\author{You Know Who}
\date{\today}

% note: do NOT include a \maketitle line; also note that this title
% material goes BEFORE the \begin{document}

% have this if you'd like a recurring outline
\AtBeginSection[]  % "Beamer, do the following at the start of every section"
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\tableofcontents[currentsection]  % show TOC and highlight current section
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{picture.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

%etc...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you check using `texify --tex-option=--src foo.tex` as mentioned in [texify miktex documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html) as `--src` option passes `--src-specials to the TeX compiler`.

Comment: I'm running WinEdt on windows, so I'm not sure how/where to set this option...

Comment: can you run from the [Command window](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) `texify --tex-option=--src your-filename.tex` to ensure if it is problem. Later you can follow [winedt doc](http://www.winedt.org/Doc/FAQ/) and [winedt configure](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.ca/2010/04/winedt-60-for-latex-features.html) to set it up. I hope you have Ghostscript installed.

Comment: @texenthusiast: The error message is from the miktex ghostscript: So obviously a ghostscript is installed. Paul: You should make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem so that other can test it.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) means starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It will help someone here to assist you.

Comment: @texenthusiast:  I have updated the question with a minimum working example.  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that, when you say ''anytime I try to scroll down the document'' you mean you are trying to visualize it in Yap.

I've had the same problem in some `.dvi` documents of mine and I've solved changing the `Render Method` to `Dvips`.

To do this in Yap, go to `View` -> `Render Method` and change it from `Pk` to `Dvips`.

If you want to change it globally, go to `View` -> `Options` -> `Display` -> `Default Render Method` and do the same as above.