# Error viewing dvi file: Postscript specials could not be rendered

Tags: errors, miktex, yap

How to rectify this error while viewing `.dvi` file,

```
*******
Error: /undefined in H.S
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1930   1   3   %oparray_pop   1929   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1176/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:17/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

*************
```

my tex [file](http://websoftz.com/file/gsm25.tex)

Comment: Did you include `-src-specials` while running `latex` like `latex -src-specials `samplefile.tex` which incorporates source specials into the `samplefile.dvi` file ?

Comment: You should add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that); your TeX file is far from minimal `:)`

Comment: Please pare down your example.  A 9000 line document is not a MWE.

Comment: Also, `gsm-l` is not a class I have.  Please use a more standard class for your MWE.

Comment: See my update below.

Comment: It looks to me the same error as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100260/27635. My answer there tells you how to solve the problem.

Comment: @A.Ellett -- `gsm-l` is based on `amsbook.cls` so that should be usable as a substitute *in this case*.

Answer (score 9):

This problem occurs sometimes when compiling a tex file with latex and using a dvi viewer like YAP.

Not sure what exactly causes the problem. In my case, I used MikTex 2.9 to compile a tex file and yap.exe that came along with the MikTex distribution to view the dvi file.

After some browsing on the web, I found that this error might occur if you 
have included the package hyperref. There are other possibilities as well, which I don't fully understand.

Accordingly, there are two solutions that I found on the web:

1. Change the rendering method from Pk to Dvips.
   Open Yap: From the menu, select View --> Render Method --> Dvips.

   Although this solves the problem, the dvips rendering method is extremely slow and can cut productivity. To see this, just try compiling a 30 page tex file and scrolling down the resulting dvi file.  For more details on rendering methods in yap, see http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/02/Yap-24-render-method.aspx.
2. The second solution works if you have included the package hyperref. Then 
   use the hypertex-driver with hyperref, i.e., \usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}. 
   Note that you will have to remove this driver option if you want to process the dvi with dvips.

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/jVyH1xat-9Q

Sometimes, even though you may not have explicitly included the hyperref package, it is possible that it might be contained as part of the class file. To make sure, open the document class file you are loading and if hyperref package is loaded, change it to include the hypertex option.

NOTE: The hypertex option will cause all hyperlinks in the document to be underlined. If you do not want this, then retain it while developing the tex file, so that you can continue using Yap with Pk rendering, and later remove it in the final version.

Answer (score 2):

This is encountered very frequently at the AMS in production.  (And `gsm-l` is an AMS document class, based on `amsbook.cls`.)

There is no really good solution for viewing such output with a `.dvi` viewer; we don't know of a single one that invariably handles all PostScript "special" code.

The solution used as AMS when this occurs is to convert the `.dvi` file to pdf and view that with a reliable pdf viewer.

The reference ([Problems rendering BeamerTex Postscript specials in WinEdt 6.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100260/27635)) given in a comment by karlkoeller provides a specific implementation of this solution.  If the system used by the OP is the same as that in the referenced question, the present question can be considered a duplicate.
Other installations have different tools.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the sort of error you get when you include `pstricks` material in your document and either:

(1) you typed some `pstricks` commands incorrectly, or

(2) you're not compiling appropriately for a document which includes `post-script` commands.   Try using the

```
latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf
```

route if you're not already.  (Though I'm inclined to think that  you've probably mistyped some code that refers to post scripts.)

I might be able to help you more if you include a MWE illustrate code that duplicates this error.

**UPDATE**

Well, I dove into your not so minimal-MWE.

I made the following changes:

1. I changed the class to the book class
2. I made sure I was loading `amsthm` and `amsmath`
3. Since I have none of your `eps` files, I substituted `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` for all of them.

Once I'd done this.  The document compiles fine regardless of whether I use `pdflatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.

I would suggest that you examine the images you're importing.  One of them is perhaps a bit wonky.  Otherwise, you might want to talk to others who use the same documentclass.  It's possible that there's something in the documentclass itself which is expecting *postscripts* or something to generate the error you're getting.

Also, I might suggest that you load the `enumitem` package or something comparable.  I notice that in several places you write:

```
\item[1)]
```

and so forth.  You should leave the numbering to LaTeX.  If you load the `enumitem` package, then you can write something along the lines of

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $C(Q)$ is an associative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra with 1;
\item $J:V\rightarrow C(Q)$ is a linear map and.....
```

which is much more flexible and easier to manage if you decide to move things around.

To get the effect of `\item[a)]` you can use

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
```

*Additionally*, I notice you use `$$...$$` for displayed math.  This is generally depricated.  It would be better to replace this with `\[...\]`.

Comment: ill add my tex file link Ellett, guide me to clear this error

Comment: im now checking on image files

Comment: I would suggest you first change the class and add teh two packages `amsthm` and `amsmath` before hunting through all your images.  Because.... if by doing that there is no more error, then you can eliminate the images as a likely source of your problem.  It then most likely lies in the class that you're using:  which I assume you have little choice about.

Comment: @A.Ellett -- changing the class file won't make and difference in this case.  the cause of the problem is *definitely* some postscript code that exceeds what is able to be interpreted by most `.dvi` viewers.  the solution (used at ams in production) is to convert the output to pdf for viewing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good to know. I neither did I realize this was an ams package.