# preview generates error

Tags: errors, miktex, preview

when attempting to view a latex document in texniccenter I get

```
MiKTeX Problem Report Message: Some PostScript specials could not be
rendered. Data: Error: /undefined in H.S Operand stack: 
--nostringval-- PermitFileReading --nostringval-- PermitFileWriting --nostringval-- Execution stack: %interp_exit  .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2  %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--  false 1 %stopped_push 1930 1 3 %oparray_pop 1929 1 3 %oparray_pop 1913 1 3 %oparray_pop 1803
1 3  %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2
--nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:  --dict:1176/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:80/200(L)-- --dict:100/300(L)-- --dict:17/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Dvi\Ghostscript.cpp Line: 362 MiKTeX: 2.9 OS:
Microsoft Windows 8 Business Edition, 64-bit (build 9200) Invokers:
non-existing/explorer/TeXnicCenter SystemAdmin: no PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Johannes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 Root1:
C:\Users\Johannes\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9 Root2:
C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9 Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Johannes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 UserConfig:
C:\Users\Johannes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 UserData:
C:\Users\Johannes\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9 CommonInstall: C:\Program
Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9 CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

I'm clueless how can I view or pdf my document?

Comment: Please provide us with your LaTeX code but make it as simple as possible just for the sake of reproducing your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Take a look at this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100260/27635 and see if the answer helps you solve the problem.